Memory overflow can't figure it out
So I am trying to answer this exercise from Eloquent Javascript Chapter 4 (The sum of a range) (check the bottom of the page).
My problem is I am getting "Uncaught out of memory" error when running certain combinations like for the example I pasted here.
I don't see anything wrong with the code. If I changed the range call to a start/end from 35, 30, -1 to, for example, 30, 35, 2 I would get a result so I am confused.
Appreciate any help.
https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html


let all = [];

function range (start, end, step = 1) {

  if (start < end) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) 
      all.push(i);
  }
  else if (start > end) {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i -= step) 
      all.push(i);
  }
  else 
    throw new Error 
    ("Start is equal to End or something else went wrong! Check your input"); 
  
  return all;
}

range(35, 30, -1);

console.log(all);




While you check that start is larger or smaller than end to go through the range in the right direction, you don't assert that i += step will actually increase the value of i or that i -= step will actually decrease the value of i.

I don't think step should ever be equal or smaller than 0

@HaoWu The instructions in the book are clear: "Make sure this also works with negative step values so that range(5, 2, -1) produces [5, 4, 3, 2]."

Using arguments (35, 30, -1) the 2nd for loop will trigger.
With values substituted that reads:
for (let i = 35; i >= 30; i -= (-1)) 
  all.push(i);

You made the step argument negative, but are also decreasing by that value, which in effect means you are adding 1 to i. In that case the loop end condition is never reached (i goes from 35 towards +infinity, i >= 30 never becomes false), leading to an array overflow.
You probably want to limit step to values of 1 and higher, and let the for loop decide if it does += or -= with that value.

THANK YOU I can't believe I didn't notice that. Everything works now.
